# Javascript and ASP.NET 2.0: How can I know if the page is valid (after validation takes place) in Javascript code on the client?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation, client-side

I need to know if all the client-side validator checks have succeeded, or if one or more validators are not valid.

I suppose there should be a variable on the client-side (like its counterpart Page.IsValid on the server) that reports whether the page is valid. Am I right?

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the client side check Page_IsValid global variable, details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0(VS.80).aspx)